# Postgres select where jsonb array contains one or more elements in another array

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I've got a postgres column 'data' which is jsonb in this format:

```
{
  'tags': ['friend','enemy','frenemy']
  ... // other data
}
```

Say I want to select all rows that are tagged either 'enemy' or 'frenemy', how can i do that?

I know I can select on a single tag with

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.data->'tags' ? 'enemy'
```

I should be using `@> ANY`, but can't quite figure out the syntax for the to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer tucked away in [this SO question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130699/postgresql-json-query-array-against-multiple-values).

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE people.data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['enemy','frenemy']
```